# Dayjs with Nuxt/Vue: Button to change timezone

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, dayjs

I've been tinkering around with a booking system using dayjs. Currently it imports objects with a DateTime in the 'Australia/Melbourne' timezone, and I'm looking to make a dropdown that changes the timezone that it's currently being displayed in. However, I haven't had any luck getting the display to change. I've even got it to reload the component, but it doesn't seem to do the trick.

Component that will change the timezone:

```html
<div>
      <button @click="changeTimezone('SA')" >
          Set timezone to Adelaide
      </button>

      <button @click="changeTimezone('WA')" >
          Set timezone to Perth
      </button>

      <button @click="changeTimezone('NSW')" >
          Set timezone to Sydney
      </button>

      <div><span>data timezone</span>{{ currentTimeZoneOutput }}</div>
      <div><span>computed timezone</span>{{ computedTimeZoneOutput }}</div>


</div>
```

Script:

```js
export default {

  data() {
    return {
        currentTimeZoneOutput: this.$dayjs(Date.now()).format("h:mm:ss A"),
    };
  },
  methods: {
      changeTimezone(state){
        this.$store.commit('SET_TIMEZONE', state)
        this.$dayjs.tz.setDefault(this.$store.state.timezone)
      },
      forceRerender(){
          this.$emit("forceRerender");
      }
  },
  computed: {
      computedTimeZoneOutput (){
          return this.$dayjs(Date.now()).format("h:mm:ss A")
      }
  }
}
```

The store mutation:

```js
 SET_TIMEZONE: (state, newTimezone) => {

    switch(newTimezone){
      case 'NT':
        state.timezone = 'Australia/Darwin'
        break;

      case 'WA':
        state.timezone = 'Australia/Perth'
        break;
          
      case 'VIC':
        state.timezone = 'Australia/Victoria'
        break;
        
      case 'QLD':
        state.timezone = 'Australia/Brisbane'
        break;
        
      case 'NSW':
        state.timezone = 'Australia/Sydney'
        break;
        
      case 'ACT':
        state.timezone = 'Australia/Canberra'
        break;
        
      case 'TAS':
        state.timezone = 'Australia/Tasmania'
        break;
        
      case 'SA':
        state.timezone = 'Australia/Adelaide'
        break;

      default:
        state.timezone = newTimezone
    }

    console.log('Timezone is now: ' + state.timezone)}
```

Something tells me I'm not actually able to change the timezone dynamically. If anyone could point me in the right direction that would be great, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `mapState` in this situation:

*Script*

```js
import { mapState } from 'vuex'
export default {
  data() {
    return {
        currentTimeZoneOutput: this.$dayjs(Date.now()).format("h:mm:ss A"),
    };
  },
  methods: {
      changeTimezone(state){
        this.$store.commit('SET_TIMEZONE', state)
        this.$dayjs.tz.setDefault(this.timezone) // EDITED
      },
      /** 
      * No need for this. By force re-rendering you run data() again 
      * too. So it will be the same each time.
      */
      /* forceRerender(){
          this.$emit("forceRerender");
      } */
  },
  computed: {
      ...mapState(['timezone'])
  }
}
```

Now inside your template use `timezone` from computed property.

```html
...
<div><span>data timezone</span>{{ timezone }}</div>
```

A very good explanation about `mapState` is in this [link](https://jerickson.net/basics-of-mapstate-vuex/).

Comment: I don't think that is the issue. I think it's something to do with:
        this.$dayjs.tz.setDefault(this.$store.state.timezone), because changing the timezone here doesn't recalculate all of the dayjs functions that are already displayed on the page.

Comment: If I were you, I would put the ``changeTimeZone`` as an action inside store and dispatch it and change the calculated time there. And use ``mapState`` to get it. But in your situation you are calling ``changeTimezone`` method with changed state inside your component which is not a good approach. This is not how it supposed to work. You need to change the state inside the store, and access the changes via ‍‍``mapState``. I edited my answer. Check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Okay turns out - needed to add UTC to the dates first.

So instead of (for example):

```
this.$dayjs(Date.now()).tz("America/New_York").format("h:mm:ss A")
```

It becomes:

```
this.$dayjs.utc(Date.now()).tz("America/New_York").format("h:mm:ss A")
```

Now my dates are finally reactive!